# R - Using an if else statement to categorise sickness type based on the number of days off?

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr

I am currently trying to find out how many people in a company have 3 days off out of the prior consecutive 5 in a year.

The following fake data is listed below for an example:

```
structure(list(Region = c("20SUSSX", "20SUSSX", "20SUSSX", "20SUSSX", 
"20SUSSX", "20SUSSX", "20SUSSX", "20SUSSX", "20SUSSX", "20SUSSX", 
"20SUSSX", "20SUSSX", "20SUSSX", "20SUSSX", "20SUSSX", "20SUSSX", 
"20SUSSX", "20SUSSX", "20SUSSX", "20SUSSX"), On_date = structure(c(16122, 
16123, 16127, 16128, 16129, 16130, 16132, 16133, 16134, 16135, 
16279, 16280, 16281, 16282, 16286, 16287, 16290, 16291, 16444, 
16458), class = "Date"), Name = c("bob", "bob", "bob", "bob", 
"bob", "bob", "bob", "bob", "bob", "bob", "bob", "bob", "bob", 
"bob", "bob", "bob", "bob", "bob", "bob", "bob"), Sickness_Type = c("?", 
"?", "?", "?", "?", "?", "?", "?", "?", "?", "?", "?", "?", "?", 
"?", "?", "?", "?", "?", "?")), .Names = c("Region", "On_date", 
"Name", "Sickness_Type"), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

With this data frame, my aim is to use an if else statement in the 'Sickness_Type' variable that enters a 1 if sickness occurs for 3 out of the previous 5 days and a 0 if it is has occurred less frequently than this. A row is only present for an employee where sickness is present.

I am unsure how to do this due to my lack of familiarity with the date formats in R. Currently I have been trying using dplyr's mutate and if_else but had no luck.

Any help on this would be much appreciated,

Thanks!

Comment: How is sickness identified?

Comment: Sorry should have made it clearer. The data frame only includes entries for days where an employee is sick. Thanks! @docendodiscimus

Comment: by 'previous 5 days' you mean consecutive days? i.e. are 21/02, 22/02, 26/02 consider 3 days or 6?

Comment: Not sure if I got it. Can you provided the desired output? My first guess is something along this line: `seq_along(df$On_date)-findInterval(df$On_date-5.1,df$On_date)>=3`

Comment: @George It would be very helpful for you to point out an instance that should be classified as sickness, and and instance that that is not.

Comment: Just to clarify: By the previous 5 days I mean based on calendar dates as opposed to previous 5 days in the data frame. So if it was the 5th January I would count the number of sick days for that person from the 1st Jan to the 5th Jan. If this number was equal to 3 or more then a '1' should be put in the new column. Row 20 would get 0, whilst row row 10 would get a 1. Thank you

Comment: Keith's solution has worked using the dplyr lag function. Thanks for your help with this :)

Comment: but it does not take into account the calendar dates...just dates appearing on the data frame

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you can achieve this using dplyr's [`lag` function](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/window-functions.html), e.g.:

```
dat %>% 
    group_by(Name) %>% 
    arrange(On_date) %>%
    mutate(Sickness_Type=ifelse(On_date - lag(On_date, 3) <= 5, 1, 0))
```

The `lag(On_date, 3)` retrieves the date of the third entry before the current one, so if this is less than or equal to five, then you know there have been three sicknesses in that time range.

The result is:

```
    Region    On_date  Name Sickness_Type
     <chr>     <date> <chr>         <dbl>
1  20SUSSX 2014-02-21   bob            NA
2  20SUSSX 2014-02-22   bob            NA
3  20SUSSX 2014-02-26   bob            NA
4  20SUSSX 2014-02-27   bob             0
5  20SUSSX 2014-02-28   bob             0
6  20SUSSX 2014-03-01   bob             1
7  20SUSSX 2014-03-03   bob             1
8  20SUSSX 2014-03-04   bob             1
9  20SUSSX 2014-03-05   bob             1
10 20SUSSX 2014-03-06   bob             1
11 20SUSSX 2014-07-28   bob             0
12 20SUSSX 2014-07-29   bob             0
13 20SUSSX 2014-07-30   bob             0
14 20SUSSX 2014-07-31   bob             1
15 20SUSSX 2014-08-04   bob             0
16 20SUSSX 2014-08-05   bob             0
17 20SUSSX 2014-08-08   bob             0
18 20SUSSX 2014-08-09   bob             1
19 20SUSSX 2015-01-09   bob             0
20 20SUSSX 2015-01-23   bob             0
```

Obviously, you will need to handle the cases where there are not that many previous days, leading to NA's.

A straight-forward way to do that would be to add a second nested `ifelse` statement with an `is.na()`.

Comment: Wouldn't you need to group by (at least) the `Name` column?

Comment: Yes, I would group by `Name` and arrange by `On_date` to be sure. I also thought the current day should be counted towards the total. Still, a very elegant solution. I tried using a `rollapply` sliding window approach but the code to handle the beginning of the timeframe became much more complicated than this.

Comment: Good suggestions! I updated the snippet to group by `Name` and order by `On_date`.